# Why I can't access global scope?

Tags: javascript

I have a function like this:

```
const doIt = (name => {
   const aLocalVarible = {};
   const obj = {
      one: function(name) {
         Console.log(name);
         //Says that the name variable has a value
         window[name]();
         //Some code
      },
      two: function() {
         //Some code
      }
   };
   return obj;
})();
```

As you can see, It's a self invoking function with closures. To define `aLocalVarible` only for its scope. Everything is fine. but that line `window[name]();` which is used to call a variable function doesn't work.

When I run:

```
doIt.one('getData');
```

I get this:

```
TypeError: window[name] is not a function
```

So why can't it access the global scope? While the function with passed name exists.

**EDIT:**
For more clarification, it is the function which its name is passed.
It is in global scope.

```
const getData = () => {
   alert('pagination!');
};
```

Comment: What name are you using when you call it? Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: What is stored in `window.someName`? It appears to be something other than a function

Comment: Does the window object have this `someName` attribute or function?

Comment: It's the name of a function which I've defined. It exists. And it's not a forbidden word. It's `getData`

Comment: Why does the IIFE take a `name` parameter that it never uses, and you never pass a value for?

Comment: Could you show us the code that adds `getData` to the window object?

Comment: @Nicholas Tower it's a function like the other functions

Comment: but is it 'attached' to the `window` object? did you add it to it?

Comment: Why don't you want to just show how you define it in the question? Post an executable [mcve].

Comment: @blurfus yes it's a function. I've defined it

Comment: What are `aLocalVariable` and `two` for?

Comment: Add `console.log(typeof window[name])`

Comment: The error message is not lying. It has nothing to do with scope. It has to do with what that property is. I cannot reproduce what you are saying. Please prove your point by making a runnable snippet inside the question (using the toolbar), which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Does the function have the same name as the ID of a DOM element? IDs become `window` properties, and this can replace the function.

Comment: `const getData = () => {` This will not be put onto the window object. Not unless you add code to do so. `var`s have a sneaky behavior that does that, but they fixed that with `let` and `const`

Comment: @Barmar it's just to show you the schema. A whole view.

Comment: try `var getData = ...` and if this script is global and not type=module it should place getData on the window. alternatively you can explicitly put it on the window by `window.getData = ...`

Comment: @Andrei I tried it and it worked. Thanks man. Can you post that as an answer with more details?

Comment: That's why I was asking if you had added `someName` to the `window` object.  Unless you do so, you have no guarantees it will be there to invoke it the way you are doing it.

Comment: @blurfus Isn't it supposed that whatever we define in global scope, must be in global scope? I don't get it. It's working with `var`, not with `const`

Comment: Yes, it's not always the case... I don't get the diff either but it is not automatic either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try `var getData = ...` and if this script is global and not type="module" it should place getData on the window. alternatively you can explicitly put it on the window like this: `window.getData = ...`